# Duplicity able to restore even though wrong passphrase

Tags: duplicity

I was able to restore my encrypted backup even with random password. How come?
Creating backing by:

```
export PASSPHRASE=$(cat /var/password.txt)
PASSPHRASE="$PASSPHRASE" duplicity \
    --encrypt-key 1223455JJ \
    --rsync-options "-avPt --rsync-path=\"sudo rsync\"" \
    --asynchronous-upload \
    --include '/some/folders' \
    .
    .
    .
    / \
    rsync://...
```

And when restoring, I just simply input any password, and to my surprise my files could be restored!

```
duplicity --force restore file:///thebackup /to/some/path
```

Any idea what's the mistake I did?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the answer to my question. It seems like gpg-agent cached the passphrase during backup. And since I generated my key using gpg2, Duplicity will always search for cached passphrase, as mentioned in [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/duplicity) under --use-agent:

> GnuPG 2 and newer ignore this option and will always use a running
>   gpg-agent if no passphrase was delivered